# ReactiveCocoa: creating a signal that applies a map over an observer

Tags: objective-c, swift, reactive-cocoa, reactive-cocoa-4

From what I understand, the `RACSubject` equivalent of ReactiveCocoa 4 is the `Observer` class.
I want to have a signal and an observer linked together so that the signal sends events applying a map operation to the events sent to the observer.
In Obj-C it looks like this:

```
// ViewModel.h

@interface ViewModel

@property (readonly) RACSubject *someAction; //expects e.g. int values
@property (readonly) RACSignal *someSignal; //sends e.g. string values

@end

// ViewModel.m

//redeclaring the signal and action as readwrite

@implementation

- (id)init {
  _someAction = [RACSubject subject];
  _someSignal = [_someAction map:^id(NSNumber *index) {
     return "Some string based on index passed in";
  }];
}

@end
```

Now when someone pushes a value onto `someAction`, the `someSignal` will fire an event containing a derived value.
How do I achieve the same effect in Swift?

What I've been able to do so far is something like this:

```
public class ViewModel: NSObject {
    public let (internalSignal, someAction) = Signal<Int, NoError>.pipe()
    public var someSignal: Signal<String, NoError> {
        get {
            return self.internalSignal.map({ [unowned self](index: Int) -> String in
                return "Some string value based on \(self.someArray[index])"
            })
        }
    }
    public let someArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
}
```

Which looks like a bad solution because

1. `internalSignal` should be private but needs to be declared public in order to match it to Signal's pipe
2. `someSignal` is computed every time it's needed therefore, even though the same signal could be reused over and over. Also can't be declared as a `let` constant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could initialize the members in `init` just like ObjC...

```
public class ViewModel: NSObject {
    private let internalSignal: Signal<Int, NoError>
    public let someAction: Observer<Int, NoError>
    public let someSignal: Signal<String, NoError>

    override init() {
        (internalSignal, someAction) = Signal<Int, NoError>.pipe()
        someSignal = internalSignal.map { index in
            "Some string value based on \(index)"
        }
        super.init()
    }
}
```

---

For `someSignal` you could also use [lazy initialization](http://mikebuss.com/2014/06/22/lazy-initialization-swift/), which allows the member to refer to `self`:

```
public class ViewModel: NSObject {
    private let internalSignal: Signal<Int, NoError>
    public let someAction: Observer<Int, NoError>
    public private(set) lazy var someSignal: Signal<String, NoError> =
        self.internalSignal.map { [unowned self] index in
            "Some string value based on \(self.someArray[index])"
        }

    override init() {
        (internalSignal, someAction) = Signal<Int, NoError>.pipe()
        super.init()
    }
}
```

Unlike the first piece of code, the lazy-var is initialized only before `someSignal` is used, not at the ViewModel's initialization.

Also, since it is a `var`, Swift allows you use mutate its value (there is no such thing as `lazy let`). We can restrict the permission using `private(set)`, but this won't prevent you accidentally write `self.someSignal = ...` somewhere.

---

Alternatively, you could make `someSignal` an implicitly unwrapped optional and initialize manually:

```
public class ViewModel: NSObject {
    private let internalSignal: Signal<Int, NoError>
    public let someAction: Observer<Int, NoError>
    public private(set) var someSignal: Signal<String, NoError>!

    override init() {
        (internalSignal, someAction) = Signal<Int, NoError>.pipe()
        super.init()
        someSignal = internalSignal.map { [unowned self] index in
            "Some string value based on \(self.someArray[index])"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the amazingly quick answer. The only problem would then be that in the map closure `self` cannot be used because we're still in init. Let me rephrase the question a bit.

Comment: Although I don't quite like the amount of extra code needed to write such a simple idea, I nevertheless thank you kindly for your help. Answer accepted. Thanks!